# Fluent UI GroupedList Selection

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, office-ui-fabric-react, fluentui-react

Playing with FluentUI and trying to make GroupedList working, but I'm stuck and have so many questions about Selection:
This is my example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-chebyshev-n4enr?file=/src/GroupedList.Basic.Example.tsx

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- I need to display the name of selected item;
- In a list of items I'd like to be able to select any (currently, only the last one can be selected)
- I would like to have the first item automatically selected after it's been added;

Please help